# xamarin forms simulador iOS no funciona

Tags: xamarin.forms, microsoft, xamarin.ios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Ya voy varias horas intentando solucionarlo pero no veo la solución en ningún lado.
Actualmente estoy construyendo una aplicación movil para android y iOS con autenticacion de MSAL con active directory de azure.
La ventana de autenticación en android funciona perfectamente; pero en el simulador de iOS no he logrado hacerlo funcionar.

descargué el ejemplo de github [mal en xamarin forms](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2)

y he tratado de ejecutarlo en iOS pero me sale el error

```html
Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error  Could not find any available provisioning profiles for UserDetailsClientiOS on iOS. UserDetailsClient.iOS
```

cualquier guía que pueda servirme se los agradeceré. Gracias!!

Comment: Tienes instalado los Profiles de Desarrollo y de Producción en tu App? Te los descargas de tu cuenta de Apple Developer.

Comment: visual studio ya tiene agregado la cuenta de apple id; pero en la configuración del proyecto esta configurado como:
Firma de lote--> Aprovisionamiento manual-Developer automatic y en derechos personalizados esta cargado el archivo de Entitlements.plist

Comment: Igual que en Xcode, cuando te logueas con tu cuenta debes descargar e instalar los Profiles para que se agregue al KeyChain. A eso hace referencia el error, intenta con Aprovisionamiento Automático.

Comment: Entonces lo que tengo que hacer es crearme un perfil de aprovisionamiento y descargar en el visual studio y en el xcode.
Lo probaré gracias.

Comment: para el aprovisionamento automatico necesito de un dispositivo real?

Comment: No es necesario, es para que automáticamente descargue e instale los Profiles y  Certificados.

Comment: encontré este https://luisdavidxamshap.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/ejecutar-aplicaciones-xamarin-forms-en-dispositivos-o-simuladores-ios/
donde indica como hacer la configuración pero no indica nada respecto a los esquemas de aprovisionamiento. Estoy confundido :C

Comment: Los tiene en automático en el Xcode, entonces ya los tiene instalado. Cómo lo tienes en Xcode?

Comment: El tutorial es del 2018 y lo que muestra son diferentes a los ahora. En la web creé mi certificado y cuando le pongo en automatico y trata de firmar el visual studio me da el error 'Error de firma automática. compruebe la ventana de salida de xamarin'.
`There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project, please check the logs.`

Comment: anteriormente me salía otro tipo de error

Comment: acabo de correrlo en automático y salió
`There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project: 'There are no current IOS devices on this team matching the provided device IDs.'`

Comment: Agrega los dispositivos en tu cuenta de Apple Developer o puedes intentar eliminando el Profile de Distribución si solo quieres utilizar el simulador para Dev.

Comment: En estos momentos no tengo un dispositivo iphone para las pruebas y no tengo profile de distribución.

Comment: Creaste algún Certificado de Distribución?

Comment: En la web de Developer.apple me aparecen 2 certificados, uno de tipo iOS development(iOS) y Development(All) en devices tengo registrado la mac donde esta conectado el visual studio y en profiles no me aparece nada.
Cuando me dijiste que crease un perfil lo creé pero no me apareció el profile, es raro...

Comment: Mi intención en sí es que mi aplicativo que trabaja con la autenticación de MSAL se ejecute en el simulador de iOS ya que no cuento con dispositivo real.

Comment: En el KeyChain debes crear un certificado de autoría de firma que te va a pedir al momento de crear el Profile.